# Can I use OpenSSL on Windows to verify my WolfSSL on my embedded device?

Tags: openssl, wolfssl

As a title, I need to verify my wolfSSL client/server on my embedded devices. May I use free OpenSSL on Windows to test against it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both libraries implement the RFC's required to secure network communication using TLS protocols. They are interoperable.

You'll want to be sure both peers are connected to the same network.